# Download dialog prompt from Websocket endpoint

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have an express server with websocket configured (I use `express-ws` for the sake of simplicity but I am not tied to it). The goal is for the backend to make some heavy calls to my database and in the meantime display a progress bar on the client. Once the data has been pulled by the backend from the database, serve the retrieved data to the client.

Here is what I do:

In my client:

```js
let ws = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/export_file' );

ws.addEventListener('message', function(m) {
   console.log(m.data);
   // Do some stuff on my UI to display the progress
});
```

In my server:

```js
import express from 'express';
import ws from 'express-ws';

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000);

// Enable websockets on routes
ws(app);

app.ws('/export_file', async (ws, req) => {
   let myData = '';
   ws.send('step 1', () => {});
   myData =+ myDB.call1();
   ws.send('step 2', () => {});
   myData =+ myDB.call2();
   ws.send('step 3', () => {});
   myData =+ myDB.call3();

   // I would like to deliver a text file with "myData" to the client here
})
```

I am stuck there... I just don't know how to trigger a download dialog prompt on my client's browser with `myData` as a text file.